# Create database with docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  # bla bla bla

  pg:
    image: postgres:9.6    
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:
      POSTGRES_DB: just_db
volumes:
  pgdata:
```

And following Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish ./src/WebApp/WebApp.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime AS final
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
COPY --from=build /app .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet"]
CMD ["WebApp.dll"]
```

As I read if I set `POSTGRES_USER`, `POSTGRES_PASSWORD` and `POSTGRES_DB` variables in `docker-compose.yml` db will be created. And sql scripts from folder `docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` will be executed. I expect database `just_db` to be created after I run `docker-compose up --build` but it doesn't happen. How do I create database with `docker-comose`?

Comment: Did you check with out volume?

Answer (score 2):

`docker-compose` will only create a database if `$PGDATA` doesn't already exist.  This is because `initdb` is only called when `$PGDATA` is empty (or more precisely, when no `PG_VERSION` file exists).  Please see the [entrypoint source for more info](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/master/9.6/docker-entrypoint.sh#L57).  Since you are providing `pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data` in your `docker-compose.yml`, Docker will simply use what's already there, and won't create an additional database named `just_db`.  If you want it to create `just_db`, then you will need to either provide a `$PGDATA` volume that is empty (or remove `PG_VERSION`, but that might make things even more messy), or omit the volume altogether.